# Exclude files from JAR build with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j2

I have a folder at the root of my Eclipse Java project to hold configuration files for the application and log4j2.  The only way I can get the in IDE build to work is to add that folder to the Java Build Path of the project.

I need to exclude either this folder or the files therein from the JAR file export.  This will allow it to look in the same folder for those 2 configuration files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the project folder in the Eclipse Package Explorer.

Select "Build Path", then, "Configure Build Path".

Go to the "Source" tab that appears. (You should be automatically selecting "Java Build Path" in the left hand side of the popup window)

Open the folder for your project, and click on "Excluded", then click "Edit" on the right hand side.

From this window, you should be able to click "Add..." in the exclusion patterns. The dialogue box should have a "Browse" button that will allow you to exclude specific classes or packages. The input also accepts wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

You could pack your dependencies project into jar(wihout excluded files). Then pack as previously.